# Creating Storyboards Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to make multiple storyboards for each screen size in Xcode 6.  I have an error in this code as you can see.

Picture

[image]

Comment: have you created a new storyboard, File -> New -> User Interface -> Storyboard?

Comment: No.  I'll try that now and see if it works.

Comment: Your code is to load the new created storyboard not to create a new one.

Comment: I can't find new storyboard.  I went File > New  but then there is not User Interface or Storyboard there.

Comment: sorry, File -> New -> File -> User Interface -> Storyboard?

Comment: But that is just another storyboard the same as the main one that it comes with. How can I make one specifically for the iPhone 3.5 inch, one for the 4 inch and so on?

Comment: I'll write a complete answer for you

Comment: Please remove the original one and keep my method :(

Comment: In Xcode?  The original method is gone.

Comment: you shouldn't edit the question like this, because when others see this question, the answer will not be belonging to it. I suggest to add new question instead. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to create a new **storyboard** from File -> New -> File -> User Interface -> Storyboard give it a name lets say "Stoaryboard_iPhone35"

Now you have a new blank one, when you place a new **UIViewController** on the new created stoaryboard select it and from the right panel -> **Attributes inspector** then from simulated metrics section -> Size and choose the destination size you need.

Repeat it for every created viewcontroller on the stoaryboard.

Repeat the whole steps for every screen size.

Now from your code you can choose the right one using its name and based on device screen size.

You need to select the correct storyboard at **application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:**
 like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = nil;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] ==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];//iPad
    } else {
        CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        if (screenSize.height == 480){
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone35" bundle:nil];//iPhone 3.5inch
        } else
        if (screenSize.height == 568){
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone5" bundle:nil];//iPhone 4inch
        }
        else
        {
            //default storyboard
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone5" bundle:nil];
        }

    }
    self.window.rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

btw: iPhone6 screen height: 667

iPhone6 plus is: 736

Comment: When getting the ViewControllers how can I set the screen size?

Comment: first select the view controller then from the right panel -> Attributes inspector then from simulated metrics section -> Size and choose the destination size you need (you can find iPhone 3.5-inch, iPhone 4-inch and so on)

Comment: Thanks.  Also the code above has an error saying: Duplicate declaration of method 'application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:'  And it won't let me build.  Also will I need write this code in for each storyboard I make?

Comment: I still have the same error.  It is staring to really annoy me. It is just this part - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

Comment: what is your problem now?

Comment: I am still having the problem with the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: I can't get it to build.

Comment: have you replaced your method with mine? and replaced mine story board names with yours? because it is worked fine with me.

Comment: Yes I have.  It all looks fine

Comment: sorry, we can't talk on chat because of your reputations.

Comment: I've taken a Screenshot and I'll edit my original post and add it.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to be doing File>New and going to User Interface and creating an empty storyboard from the selection. I've done this but make sure to tell Xcode that you want one storyboard for the iPad and another for the iPhone.

Your code is to access an already existing storyboard file in the main bundle.

Comment: Thanks got the new storyboard now.